# Create anonymous type by selector expressions

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, lambda, expression

Is there a way to dynamically project a bunch of selector expressions into a new anonymous type that can be used for e.g. .Select() statements or combined member accessors?

Let's say I've got a class with 3 properties

```
public class DummyClass {

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }

}
```

In order to access one of them using a member accessor, I can write something like this:

```
public class DummyClass...
    // x => x.Id
    public static Expression<Func<DummyClass, int>> IdAccessor = f => Id;
```

Same goes for the `Name` or `Category` member. Now I'd like to return both `Id` and `Name` as an anonymous type using both selectors.

```
// combined x => x.Id and x => x.Name into x => new { x.Id, x.Name }
return new { IdAccessor, NameAccessor }
```

However I'm stuck doing this dynamically as I'm not able to create an anonymous type using e.g. `Expression.New()` without knowing it's actual type.

---

**EDIT**

I rewrote the question with a different example that should clarify some more.

Comment: Care to elaborate? Creating an `ExpandoObject` using `Expression.New()`?

Comment: What is the context of your `return new...` statement? What are you trying to return? A selector? Or the actual anonymous type object? In any case, how do you expect to deal with the issue that anonymous types are basically useless outside the method where they are declared? This question is extremely unclear, not the least of which due to the lack of a good code example that adequately illustrates what the heck you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you really mean by "both selectors", but this is how I would make use of anonymous type; when selecting specific values from a list of objects.
Please comment if this is not what you mean.

```
var myDummies = new List<DummyClass> ...

var result = myDummes.Select(o => new 
{ 
    IdAccessor = o.Id, 
    NameAccessor = o.Name
    Header = String.Format("{0} ({1})", o.Name, o.Category)
});

foreach(var r in result) { ... }
```